# Use multiple match in elasticsearch query

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch. I want to use multiple nested matches in my query.

**My Query:**

```
         $query = [
                "bool"=> [
                      "must"=> [                    
                        [ "match" => ["category_name" => $category]],
                        [ "match" => ["category.status" => '1']],
                        [ "match" => ["default_product_low_price_with_seller.seller_detail.approve_status" => '1']],
                        [ "match" => ["is_published" => '1']],
                        [ "match" => ["brand.approve_status" => '1']]
                      ]
                    ]
                ];
```

But it returns 0 result instead of 1. **How to use different nested matches in above query?**

**MAPPING**

```
{
    "product-list":{
        "properties":{
            "id":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "category_id":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "type_id":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "brancd_id":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "has_variant":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "title":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "slug":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "model":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "aupc":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "height":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "width":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "length":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "weight":{
                "type":"string"
            },
            "is_published":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "created_at":{
                "type":"date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "updated_at":{
                "type":"date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "default_product_low_price_with_seller":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "id":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "product_id":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "product_seller_id":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "product_image_id":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "sku":{
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "price":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "selling_price":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "sale_price":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "sale_start":{
                        "type":"date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "sale_end":{
                        "type":"date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "shipping_cost":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "include_shipping_cost":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "qty":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "min_qty":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "download_limit":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "delivery_in_days":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "approval_status":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "warranty":{
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "display_in_list":{
                        "type":"string"
                    },
                    "created_at": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "updated_at": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    },
                    "status":{
                        "type":"integer"
                    },
                    "discountSale":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "discountSelling":{
                        "type":"double"
                    },
                    "sku_variants":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                            "id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "product_id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "product_sku_id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "product_attribute_id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "attribute_id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "attribute_value":{
                                "type":"string"
                            },
                           "created_at": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                            },
                            "updated_at": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                            },
                            "attribute":{
                                "type":"nested",
                                "properties":{
                                    "id":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "name":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "label":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "inputtype":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "default_value":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "select_validation":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "required":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "is_searchable":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "is_variants":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "status":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "has_variants":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "deleted":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "created_at": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                                    },
                                    "updated_at": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "attr_value":{
                                "type":"nested",
                                "properties":{
                                    "id":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "attribute_id":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    },
                                    "value":{
                                        "type":"string"
                                    },
                                    "created_at": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                                    },
                                    "updated_at": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                                    },
                                    "deleted":{
                                        "type":"integer"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "seller_detail":{
                      "type":"nested",
                      "properties":{
                          "id":{
                              "type":"integer"
                          },
                          "vendor_id":{
                              "type":"integer"
                          },
                          "approve_status":{
                              "type":"integer"
                          },
                          "seller_detail":{
                              "type":"nested",
                              "properties":{
                                  "id":{
                                      "type":"integer"
                                  },
                                  "name":{
                                      "type":"string"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                    },
                    "image":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                            "id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "image":{
                                "type":"nested",
                                "properties":{
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "product_images_id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "image": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "default_image":{
                                "type":"nested",
                                "properties":{
                                    "id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "product_images_id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "image": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "attribute_details":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "product_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "attribute_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "attributes":{
                "type":"nested",
                "properties":{
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "product_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "attribute_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "attribute_value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "attribute":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                            "id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "name":{
                                "type":"string"
                            },
                            "label":{
                                "type":"string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "attr_value":{
                        "type":"nested",
                        "properties":{
                            "id":{
                                "type":"integer"
                            },
                            "value":{
                                "type":"string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "category": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "parent_id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "slug": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "sort_order": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "status": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "title": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parent_cat":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                      "id":{
                          "type":"integer"
                      },
                      "parent_id":{
                          "type":"integer"
                      },
                      "title":{
                          "type":"string"
                      },
                      "slug":{
                          "type":"string"
                      },
                      "description":{
                          "type":"string"
                      },
                      "status":{
                          "type":"integer"
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
          },
          "category_name":{
              "type":"string"
          },
          "brand_name":{
              "type":"string"
          },
          "brand": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "approved_status": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "image": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "slug": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "product_id": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "product_rating_avg":{
              "type":"nested",
              "properties":{
                  "product_id":{
                      "type":"integer"
                  },
                  "rate":{
                      "type":"integer"
                  }
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

i have updated my answer. Above is my mapping code in my elasticsearch server.

Comment: do you have index your posts in the elasticsearch server?

Comment: Please specify the mapping of your index.

Comment: yes i have index in my elasticsearch server

Comment: @richa i have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Following is the json version of query you can use.

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "match": {
              "category_name": "TEXT"
           }
        },
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "category",
              "query": {
                 "term": {
                    "status": 1
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "default_product_low_price_with_seller",
              "query": {
                 "nested": {
                    "path": "seller_detail",
                    "query": {
                       "term": {
                          "approve_status": 1
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "term": {
              "is_published": 1
           }
        },
        {
           "nested": {
              "path": "brand",
              "query": {
                 "term": {
                    "approve_status": 1
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it is not working i am getting syntax error